# PHP: Any way to extract resource id # x in websocket server?

Tags: php, websocket

I have simple websocket server in PHP. When new client connects I get following when I do ***print_r***

```
Resource id # x
```

For an example when we get resource in PHP/MySQL if we fun following code we get array. Like wise Is there any way to extract information out of it?

```
$resource = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM `table`");
while($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resource)) {
}
```

Code as following

```
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);

//Accepting new socket
$socket_new = socket_accept($socket);
print_r($socket_new);
```

Comment: see http://php.net/function.socket-read

Comment: Are you confusing sockets with WebSockets?

Comment: @gre_gor Yes, I am referring to websocket.

Comment: I don't see any code relevant to WebSockets, just regular sockets. Are you trying to implement WebSocket protocol yourself?